# What is the right time acquisition of Sentinel 2 from Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I'm trying to get the time acquisition in hours and minutes from Sentinel 2 with Google Earth Engine. But there is two type of metadata that represent time acquisition:

```
Image.getInfo()
```

1. The ID, or the name of the file, something like this: '20170401T082001_20170401T082644_T36RXU' .
   Here the date of acquisition is 2017-04-01 and the hour is **08:20**
2. In the metadata there is a line called 'system:time_end', the parameter is by milliseconds.
   in this case: 1491035204000 witch after transformation gave me 2017-04-01-11-26-44. Here the date of acquisition is 2017-04-01 and the hour is **11:26**

Which one is the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id of the name contains: Creation Date in UTC time (yyyymmddThhmmss).
https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/naming-convention

So the difference is probably the timezone and the amount of time it takes to acquire a full sentinel tile (~6 min).